# fedora-commons MySQL database table updated to delete records but is not reflected on fez front-end

Tags: java, mysql, database, caching, fedora-commons

We have a Fedora-commons library Server which is built on JAVA and it utilizes MySQL as database and fez as the front end. 
Everything is working fine except when i tried to alter certain table to do a change. But this is not being reflected on the application.
Actually

- I have deleted few records from `fez_record_search_key_notes` table on `fezonline` database;
- Checked the whole database(through database dump) and there is no other table where this information is stored.
- Now the mysql CLI shows the correct table state
- I have restarted MySQL, httpd and fedora-commons too. Even the machine is restarted too. There is no cache server like squid on the machine.
- But if i change that field from the web interface provided it works as expected.

But the front end is still showing those deleted records. I have checked with web-proxies too and it conforms that it is not due to browser cache.

What may be the issue?

Comment: first of all you should check if these records exist in table or not by direct query on server....

Comment: @Zafar Malik I did that. And those records do not exists

Comment: you need to check in your code that data is coming from table or solr index etc...

Comment: @Zafar Malik I have gone through all the database dump and find no table with the same info. And hence i think this is the only table which contains the record.

Comment: you are correct that this is the only table as you have already checked directly in db, I am saying that some time we create index by solr etc (fix cache for some time) and app use results from there instead of table..

Comment: sorry but how could i know whether solr is used? i can't find it on $PATH and not on `ps` either. Yes i find this table has 3 indexes. how could i reload table indexes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81246/discussion-between-bishnu-and-zafar-malik).